# Unable to resolve "cannot make a static reference to a the non-static method getId() from the type Course"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, static, static-methods

Newbie learning a first REST API example in Springboot. I have this snippet in my implementation class giving the error ""cannot make a static reference to a the non-static method getId() from the type Course". The getId() method is not static but the invocation appears to be from a static method leading to this error...im confused. Appreciate any help.

```
@Override
public Course getCourse(long courseId) {
    Course c=null;
    for (Course course:list)
    {
        if(Course.getId()==courseId)
        {
            c=course;
            break;
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

My controller class:

```
@GetMapping("/courses/{courseId}")
public Course getCourse(@PathVariable String courseId)
{
    return this.courseService.getCourse(Long.parseLong(courseId));
}
```

My service class:

```
public interface CourseService {

    public List<Course> getCourses();   
    public Course getCourse(long courseId);
    
}
```

My entity class:

```
public class Course {

    private long id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    public Course(long id, String title, String description) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
    }
    public long getId() {
        return id;
}
```

Was expecting this will compile.

Comment: `Course.getId()` should be `course.getId()`.

Comment: thank you for the quick spot! i managed to complete my first REST example!